# Insert space to separate conjoined alpha and numeric strings - Python RegEx

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I need to create a regex that inserts a space between any concatenated AlphaNum combinations. For example, this is what I want:

```
8min15sec ==> 8 min 15 sec
7m12s ==> 7 m 12 s
15mi25s ==> 15 mi 25 s
```

[RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yvqCtQ/1)

I am blundering around with solutions found online, but they are a bit too complex for me to parse/modify. For example, I have this:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*
```

but it only identifies the first insertion point: 8Xmin15sec (the X)

And this

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])
```

but it only finds this point: 8minX15sec (the X)

I could sure use a hand with the full syntax for finding each insertion point and inserting the spaces.

[RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yvqCtQ/1) (same link as above)

Comment: All answers are excellent and solve the problem. **Mr. Rajwanshi's answer is the only one that does not add a space to the end of the string,** but for my purposes Mr. Evans' answer is most concise and optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following approach:

```
import re

for test in ['8min15sec', '7m12s', '15mi25s']:
    print(re.sub(r'(\d+|\D+)', r'\1 ', test).strip())
```

Which would give you:

```
8 min 15 sec 
7 m 12 s 
15 mi 25 s
```

Comment: No space is currently added at the start? So it should be ok?

Comment: This introduces an unwanted extra space at the end of string though, and will insert extra unwanted space if the string already contained spaces, which will not happen in my solution.

Comment: Yup, you are right: no space at beginning as updated - but I did prefer the earlier syntax: `re.sub(r'(\d+|\D+)', r'\1 ', test)`. Love this simple solution, although Mr. Rajwanshi is correct - it does add a space to the end of the string.

Comment: As a clear and simple workaround, the resulting string could have `.strip()` added.

Comment: My final (for future googlers): `re.sub(r'(\d+|\D+)', r'\1 ', str).strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex, which marks the point which are boundaries of numbers and alphabets with either order i.e. number first then alphabets or vice versa.

```
(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)
```

This regex `(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])` marks a point with positive lookahead to look for an alphabet and positive look behind to look for a digit.

Similarly, `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)` does same but in opposite order.

And then just replace that mark by a space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/938dYn/1)

Here is sample python code for same.

```
import re
arr = ['8min15sec', '7m12s', '15mi25s']
for s in arr:
 print (s + ' --> ' + re.sub('(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)', ' ',s))
```

Which prints following output,

```
8min15sec --> 8 min 15 sec
7m12s --> 7 m 12 s
15mi25s --> 15 mi 25 s
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
"(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)"
```

to

```
"\1 \2 "
```

https://regex101.com/r/yvqCtQ/2

And in python:

```
In [59]: re.sub(r'(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)', r'\1 \2 ',  '8min15sec')
Out[59]: '8 min 15 sec '
```

Comment: Something odd on my side... not seeing the matches/changes. [Here is what I am seeing](https://imgur.com/DmxK4WV)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. *And you're right: it does display correctly in FFox. (But not in Chrome/Opera. Very odd.)*